# Setting the position of the insert character in the tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to change the position of the insert character in a tkinter text widget. Is there a method or any other way which will help me set the position where the insert character is at in the text widget?

Comment: Just replace the whole string?

Comment: I'm not changing the contents but rather changing where the cursor is so that the next time the user types the text is inserted at the place where I define the cursor to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mark_set` method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.mark_set-method) with `insert` mark.

For example:

```
t.mark_set('insert', '2.3')
```

or

```
t.mark_set(INSERT, '2.3')
```

Above code will position a cursor after the 3rd character in 2nd line.

Comment: The index `2.3` ought to be in quotes -- it's not a floating point number but rather a string of the form "line.column".

Comment: @BryanOakley, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly.